# R plot base64 string

Tags: r, image, base64

How do I plot a b64 string of a png or jpeg,  as an image in R?

I have tried:

```
z <-"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";

plot(c(100, 250), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
image <- as.raster(base64decode(z))
rasterImage(image, 100, 300, 150, 350, interpolate = FALSE)
plot.new()
```

I am unable to use additional libraries.

Comment: When you say unable to use additional libraries, does that mean nothing or can you use `base64enc` as the function in your code suggests?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I can use the base64enc library.

Comment: Consider something like `writeBin(base64decode(z), "test.png")` to write a temporary file and then read that in.

Comment: It's a JPEG (`ff d8 ff` in the first few raw bytes) so you have to be able to use that package, too: `plot(c(100, 250), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "") ; rasterImage(as.raster(jpeg::readJPEG(base64enc::base64decode(z))), 100, 300, 150, 350, interpolate=FALSE)`. No need for temp files.